# context configuration and @PropertySource

Tags: java, spring, heroku

I have a perfectly test setup like below...

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(loader = AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class, classes = { ApplicationConfig.class })
public class myTest {
    @Autowired
    private JestClient jestClient;
    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;
    @Autowired
    private DSLContext jooq;
```

This runs well and without any problems whatsoever, but when I run the exact same part of my tested code in my running application then all hell breaks loose. Let me elaborate...

My java configuration file describes a properties file like so

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan({ "my.package" })
@PropertySource("classpath:/my/package/config/myfile.properties")
@Import(PersistenceConfig.class)
public class ApplicationConfig {
```

I am running my app on Heroku and I am therefore embedding my DI framework - Spring 3.2 into my project. Starting an app on that cloud service will require me to create a Spring framework launcher. So this is what I've did:

```
@ContextConfiguration(loader = AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class, classes = { ApplicationConfig.class })
public class ApplicationMain {

    private final static Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ApplicationMain.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Scheduler scheduler = StdSchedulerFactory.getDefaultScheduler();
        scheduler.start();

        // Choose what job to start based on a parameter
        JobDetail jobDetail = null;
        if (args != null && args.length > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
                if (args[i].equals("GO1")) {
                    jobDetail = newJob(GogJob.class).build();
```

So if an the main is called using GO1 parameter then my tested code will execute.
but then fail due to

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException
        Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException
```

I beleive that this is most certainly caused by the properties not being found...
I can't figure this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your property files are used in tests, they should be under `src/test/resources`

Comment: Very good point. I'll insert a duplicate under the test folder. But this still wouldn't help me out of my problem